# How do I hyphenate two locations?

Tags: hyphenation

I'm confused about how to hyphenate two locations in a single sentence. For instance:

"A New York and London-based agency focused on making brands heard."

or

"A New York- and London-based agency focused on making brands heard."

Which one is the right way to hyphenate?

Comment: Not an answer but you could consider rephrasing,.. *An agency operating from both New York and London*